# Which permission should be granted to view Google Cloud SQL charts?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I'm struggling to find which permission(s) exactly should be granted to view Google Cloud SQL charts? I can see the configuration data but not the charts, I'm getting the `You don't have access to this data` error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's either one of the `monitoring.dashboards` or `cloudsql.instances` permissions.

You can find the whole list of permissions in the [Project access control](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/project-access-control#roles) doc and use the [Policy Troubleshooter](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/troubleshooter?_ga=2.25430837.926148814.1635923662-163333918.1612439028&_gac=1.260004088.1636108666.Cj0KCQjwrJOMBhCZARIsAGEd4VFKw-mzGvU53Pq66RFeTeEDJ8CJ9EcXC0mnkwg_hYQsI70pdYsD-CcaAlDkEALw_wcB) to pinpoint the missing permission.

Check the [Troubleshooting access](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/troubleshooting-access) guide for detailed instructions.

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor yes, today I was granted today `Monitoring Viewer equivalent permissions` and now I can see the charts.